# About a formula in Lawrence-Venkatesh's proof on Mordell conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In [Lawrence-Venkatesh](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02721.pdf), the lemma 2.10 states that

For number fields $L/K$, and a representation $\rho:G_L\to GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ that is crystalline at all primes above $p$ and pure of weight $w$, then for any friendly prime $v$ of $K$ above $p$
$$\sum_{u|v}[L_u:K_v]a_u(\rho)=\frac{1}{2}[L:K]w$$
where $a_u(\rho)$ is the weight of the Hodge filtration at $u$ they defined before.

In the original proof of Mordell conjecture by Faltings, he used a similar formula to control the height under isogeny:

If $G$ is a $p$-divisible group over $K$ with height $h$, then
$$\sum_{v|p}[K_v:\mathbb{Q}_p]d_v=\frac{1}{2}[K:\mathbb{Q}]h$$
where $d_v$ is the dimension of the $p$-divisible group corresponding to $\{{\mathcal{G}_{n,v}}_{/\mathcal{O}_{K_v}}\}$.

My question is, is there a relationship between these two formulas, or is there a more general form for these formulas?

Comment: I don't think the second formula is true for an arbitrary $p$-divisible group $G$: for instance, for $G=\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}$ the dimension is zero, so the LHS is 0, but the height is 1, and the RHS is 1/2.

Comment: But if G is a subgroup of a $p$-divisible group $A[p^{\infty}]$ for an abelian scheme $A$ over $\mathcal{O}_{K,(p)}$ then you are right that the second formula follows from the first one: the dual Tate module $(V_p G)^{\vee}$ is a representation pure of weight one (because this is the case for $H^1_{et}(A_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_p))$, crystalline at places above $p$, and $d_v$ is the dimension of $gr^1$ of the Hodge filtration on the dual Dieudonne module $\mathbb{D}(G|_{\mathcal{O}_{K,v}})^{\vee}$ so $d_v/h$ is the Hodge weight $a_v$.